# How to upload a image to DeviantArt directly from GIMP?

Tags: software-recommendation, gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to deviantArt directly from Inkscape and GIMP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44037/how-to-upload-an-image-to-deviantart-directly-from-inkscape-and-gimp)

I want to upload a image to Da while working on it in GIMP.

How can i upload an image directly from gimp to DeviantArt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the [GIMP plugin by Martin Owens](http://doctormo.org/2011/05/19/deviantart-plugins-released/) for this .

To install add the PPA `ppa:doctormo/deviantart-plugins` ([here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)) and install gimp-plugin-dastash from the software center.

To Run Just go to Image -> Publish To -> deviantArt Stash

Screenshot (Courtesy of Webupd8) :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Source](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/05/deviantart-stash-plugins-10-for-gimp.html)

*...now whenever you create a picture or a graphic, you can upload them directly to your Deviantart account within those applications!.*

Open your Terminal and enter the below command to install the all new Deviantart stash plugins for Gimp/Inkscape in Ubuntu 11.04 (should work for 10.10 and 10.04, etc as well).

```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/deviantart-plugins
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-dastash inkscape-extension-dastash
```

Once installed, you should be able to find them via (in Gimp): "Image" -> "Publish to" -> "deviantArt Stash".

[image: Scrript]

Comment: damn just posted the answer at the same time ..

Comment: lmao..yeah, well i can delete it it's ok

Comment: nah thats not required but you can migrate the  inkscape part to this question ( http://askubuntu.com/q/44037/5149 )