# How to upload an image to deviantArt directly from Inkscape and GIMP?

Tags: software-recommendation, gimp, inkscape

How can I upload an image directly from Inkscape or GIMP to deviantArt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- You have to install the [Inkscape extension and GIMP plugin by Martin Owens](https://launchpad.net/dastash) for this .

[Add the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351) `ppa:doctormo/deviantart-plugins` and install `inkscape-extension-dastash` and `gimp-plugin-dastash` from the software center.

- To share an image in Inkscape go to `Extensions` → `Publish to` → `deviantArt Stash`.

[image]

- In GIMP go to `Image` → `Publish to` → `deviantArt Stash`.

[image]

- Fill in the necessary information in the windows that appears.

[image]

That's it, enjoy.

[Source: doctormo.org](http://doctormo.org/2011/05/19/deviantart-plugins-released/)